# Find mouse event target for position in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I don't actually want to trigger an event. I just want to find out programmatically which element will handle the `onmousedown` if the mouse is clicked at position x/y.

The purpose is to then add an interceptor to that element which `point-event: none`

Comment: `event.target`  directly gives the clicked item. ....

Answer (score 3):

```
// without pointer-events: none;
const element = document.elementFromPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
```

```
function elementsFromPoint(x, y) { // pointer-events: none;
    const elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var elementsList = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);

    var results = []
    elementsList.forEach(element => {
        var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

        if (rect.left < x && x < rect.right && rect.top < y && y < rect.bottom) {
            results.push(element)
        }
    });
    return results;
}
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const textarea = document.querySelector('#text')
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        const element = elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        console.log(element)
    })

})
```

Comment: Does this take into account specialties like "pointer-events: none"?

Comment: this is working with `pointer-events: none`

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want. From the docs of elementFromPoint: "Elements with pointer-events set to none will be ignored, and the element below it will be returned."

Comment: This is a great answer, I'll accept it for the time being. :)

Comment: "We can use mouse move event instead of mouse click" Could you explain this maybe? It's confusing me @MERN Thanks for your help

Comment: forgot that, in this case, we need calculate the element programatically

Comment: Updated answer with `getBoundingClientRect`

Comment: Was it broken before?